# Building custom Activity Stack

Tags: android

From activity A , I need to launch 3 Activities; B, C and D; such that the back stack appears to be:
A -> B -> C -> D
so that on each back press, user goes D -> C, C -> B and finally B -> A .

B,C and D have a Master-Detail relationship. A is kind of a shortcut builder.

`TaskStackBuilder` [can't do this on pre-HoneyComb builds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html).

Any possible workaround ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A should launch B. in `B.onCreate()` launch C. In `C.onCreate()` launch D.

Comment: Thanks. Solved it by using Fragments within same Activity.